# Open QDialog from Main Window in Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt

All I would like to do is to be able to open a new dialog from my MainWindow. I want to be able to design the dialog in Qt designer and then use the signals and slots editor to link a button press in my main window to the display of a new dialog. The dialog needs to have a couple of line edits and buttons in it and I want to avoid writing a new class in C++ every time i want a different dialog.

How can I link my main window to another dialog i created in qt designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to connect the signal to startup the dialog within the designer, this will have to be in the code. But you won't need a new custom class everytime, you could easily use one class implementing different widgets.

You will have to write some c++/design some dialog everytime, since you do want to have another dialog (or at least another setup in the same dialog). You could setup the dialog to have a `QStackedWidget` and have an index in the constructor for having one dialog with multiple pages.

Comment: Ahhh Well thank-you for your response although I must admit I'm a little frustrated.